# Only able to loop SQL rows once?

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know how to keep this executed.
The code inside `// CALCULATE EACH MONTH` is only executed on the first loop of `tracks`.

I have an idea that I need to store the SQL result in an array? but I really can't get it to work.

My php code is:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$monthsQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(`Reporting Date`) AS `Year`, MONTH(`Reporting Date`) AS `Month` FROM tsv ORDER BY `Reporting Date`";
$monthsResult = $conn->query($monthsQuery);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $tracks = $_POST['track'];
    $albums = $_POST['album'];
    foreach($tracks as $track) {
        echo "Partof:" . $track['partof'] . "<br>"; 
        echo "percentage:" . $track['percentage'] . "<br>";
        // CALCULATE EACH MONTH
        if ($monthsResult->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            $i = 0;
            while($monthRow = $monthsResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                $monthNum  = $monthRow["Month"];
                $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
                $monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
                echo $monthRow["Year"] . " " . $monthName . "<br>";
                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        //END MONTH CALCULATION
```

Comment: What kind of object is $conn? That will determine which library/function calls you use.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth `$conn = new mysqli` :)

Comment: For one, you didn't select the `partof`, `percentage` columns (possibly more) in your query. Using `mysqli_error($conn)` / error reporting would have told you about it, being undefined indexes.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks!... but `partof` and `percentage` is from `$_POST`... I don't think there is any errors. The while loop writes out the months and years fine for the first loop of `foreach`but the rest only prints out `partof` and `percentage`

Comment: can you add `mysqli_error($conn)` to the query and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your php, just to amuse (me) ;-) and see if anything comes of it. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes. I've done it now, but theres no errors :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would recommend doing here is reading going through all the rows and saving them to an array before foreach loop:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $tracks = $_POST['track'];
    $albums = $_POST['album'];
    $monthRows = array();

    if ($monthsResult->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            $i = 0;
            while($monthRow = $monthsResult->fetch_assoc()) {
              $monthRows[] = $monthRow;
            }
    foreach($tracks as $track) {
        echo "Partof:" . $track['partof'] . "<br>"; 
        echo "percentage:" . $track['percentage'] . "<br>";
        // CALCULATE EACH MONTH
        if (count($monthRows) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            $i = 0;
            foreach($monthRows as $monthRow) {
                $monthNum  = $monthRow["Month"];
                $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
                $monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
                echo $monthRow["Year"] . " " . $monthName . "<br>";
                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the right solution!! Thanks! I’ll try it out soon!

Comment: Glad to help. If you see that it works please select it as a correct answer.

Comment: Sure! :) I’ll do that